# using google gcloud to ssh tunnel into linux machine inside network

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, remote-desktop

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 VirtualBox machine (i.e. machine A) running on OSX connected to a university campus network. I would like to occasionally ssh into the machine from my laptop to remotely assist my colleagues, and I looked at different options.

It seems one of the options is "reverse ssh" (related to "port forwarding" or "ssh tunnelling"). My laptop does not have a fixed IP, so I can't do straight reverse ssh. The possible solution is to use a proxy machine. The idea is that when I need to assist my colleagues, they will type in the connection instructions from machine A, this will create a running GCP instance, and I will be able to then connect to machine A from the outside using this bridging (proxy?) GCP machine.

```
                                            / Academic intranet
                          +----------+     |  
                          |   GCE    |     |  +----------+
                          | instance |<----|--| Machine A|
                          +----------+     |  +----------+
                                           |  
                                            \ 



                                            / Academic intranet
                          +----------+     |  
+-------------+    ssh    |   GCE    | ssh |  +----------+
| Laptop dynIP|---------->| instance |-----|->| Machine A|
+-------------+           +----------+     |  +----------+
                                           |
                                            \
```

We have a Google cloud account and `gcloud` installed on machine A. For what I can tell, GCP already has a very simple way to set up a tunnel in GCP:

https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/ssh-tunnel-on-gce

I tried it and it works. Which makes me guess that the same should be possible on GCP for the final step: for me to be able to open an SSH browser window on the running GCP instance so that I can ssh into machine A from there.

Any ideas?

EDITED:

Here is how far I got following the ssh tunnel on gce instructions:

On machine A:

```
gcloud compute instances create --zone us-west1-a tunnel
gcloud compute ssh --zone us-west1-a tunnel -- -N -p 22 -D localhost:2210
```

On my laptop, I can open https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/instances and then open a browser window to SSH connect.

From the GCP instance hostname `tunnel`, I guess I am missing something like:

```
ssh-into-machine-A-from-here
```

This is the last command that I am missing. Or maybe the ssh tunnel in `gcloud` needs extra flags/parameters.

Comment: It looks like it should work but I'm not seeing any need to run gcloud on machine A.  See the following ... https://blog.devolutions.net/2017/3/what-is-reverse-ssh-port-forwarding

Your initial goal seems to be to ssh into the GCP Compute Engine (CE) using native ssh ... see https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-advanced

Comment: It works to the point where I can ssh into the tunnel machine that has been created by machine A. But from there, I don't know how to then ssh into machine A. I guess I am missing that last ssh command, or that setting up the tunnel needs other flags/parameters.

Comment: It looks like this is the key ... https://blog.devolutions.net/2017/3/what-is-reverse-ssh-port-forwarding

If I am reading this correctly, from machine A you would SSH into the CE at GCP using the special flags.  This would then cause the SSH on the CE to start listening on a local port.  You would then login to the CE and execute a local SSH on the CE which would then use the existing connection set up by the first command.

Comment: Following your last update .... it looks like if you login to your CE, you should then be able to run

ssh -p 2210 username@localhost

where the username is the username on machine A

Comment: Thanks @Kolban do I need to change any parameters above in my question or simply issue the two `gcloud` commands, then do `ssh -p 2210 username@localhost` in the GCP instance?

Comment: I didn't understand your scenario completely, but I believe [this](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/using-tcp-forwarding) might help you.

Comment: Thanks for the link @llompalles . It could be that the final ssh command, the one that will allow me to connect to machine A from a running GCP instance, requires special credentials like the ones explained in the link you provide. Having read through it, the examples are always about connecting to the GCP instance when they don't have a name, rather than connecting to machine A from a running ssh connection of the GCP instance. Maybe the last command I need is really easy and I am missing the point somewhere.

Comment: I added a diagram to explain what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

0) Create an instance on GCP with a command like:

```
gcloud compute instances create --zone us-west1-a tunnel
```

0b) Click on the 'SSH' link on https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/instances to open a browser window.

0c) On the browser window, edit the sshd_config file to enable `GatewayPorts yes`.

0d) Set up gcloud CLI and connect the first time as shown below:

```
gcloud compute ssh --zone us-west1-a tunnel
```

This will create the ssh keys in `$HOME/.ssh/google_compute_engine`. Disconnect from it. Now that the keys are created, follow the next steps.

1) To establish forwarding from GCE to machine A: run following on machine A:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o CheckHostIP=no -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -f -N -R 2022:*:22 gce_user@gce_address
```

2) Now, to connect to machine A from your laptop, you can use the browser window with the GCP instance and do:

```
ssh -p 2022 A_machine_user@localhost
```

This should then ask for the password on A_machine_user and connect you to machine A.

Comment: I will try @konstantin-svintsov . How do I get the gce_address from a running ssh session of the tunnel GCE machine? And how do I enable GatewayPorts on GCE sshd configuration. Is that a flag on the `gcloud compute instances create` command or the `gcloud compute ssh` command? Thanks in advance.

Comment: * The sshd_config is located in /etc/ssh/sshd_config
* gce_user - I managed to create a new user only for this and add the public ssh key the ssh keys in VM instance details.
* I had to expose the new port using firewall settings: https://docs.bitnami.com/google/faq/administration/use-firewall/

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure that I got your exact question, but as far as I understood creating a VPN should be the best solution for you. The best and safest way of connecting your GCE instance with the machine A.

You can find [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/817859/what-are-fast-and-safe-options-to-setup-a-vpn-between-the-office-and-gcp) a discussion on the same kind of implementation.

Another option, which is in the same spirit is to a Virtual private server like [OpenSSH](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openssh-server.html) on Machine A. [Here](https://www.maketecheasier.com/reverse-ssh-tunnel-allow-external-connections/) there is a guide on how to implement that using a Virtual Private Server like OpenSSH and how to configure it.